# Reformatting and Reordering Dates in a Python Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, format

I have a pandas DataFrame and I want to reformat AND order the Date Range column.
This is the `df.head()`:

```
Numeric Index   Origin Movement ID  Origin Display Name Destination Movement ID Destination Display Name    Date Range  Mean Travel Time (Seconds)  Range - Lower Bound Travel Time (Seconds)   Range - Upper Bound Travel Time (Seconds)
0   0   1074    Traffic Zone 02047  28  Traffic Zone 16024  1/4/2016 - 1/4/2016, Every day, Daily Average   2296    1593    3309
1   1   1074    Traffic Zone 02047  29  Traffic Zone 16025  1/4/2016 - 1/4/2016, Every day, Daily Average   2378    1662    3402
2   2   1074    Traffic Zone 02047  35  Traffic Zone 14080  1/4/2016 - 1/4/2016, Every day, Daily Average   1846    1703    2000
3   3   1074    Traffic Zone 02047  43  Traffic Zone 14072  1/4/2016 - 1/4/2016, Every day, Daily Average   1797    1647    1959
4   4   1074    Traffic Zone 02047  48  Traffic Zone 16027  1/4/2016 - 1/4/2016, Every day, Daily Average   2301    1670    3168
```

My `df['Date Range']` strings are dates from January 2nd 2016 to March 31st 2020 and they are in the following format:

```
1      1/4/2016 - 1/4/2016, Every day, Daily Average
2      1/4/2016 - 1/4/2016, Every day, Daily Average
3      1/4/2016 - 1/4/2016, Every day, Daily Average
4      1/4/2016 - 1/4/2016, Every day, Daily Average
                           ...                      
542    1/2/2016 - 1/2/2016, Every day, Daily Average
543    1/2/2016 - 1/2/2016, Every day, Daily Average
544    1/2/2016 - 1/2/2016, Every day, Daily Average
545    1/2/2016 - 1/2/2016, Every day, Daily Average
546    1/2/2016 - 1/2/2016, Every day, Daily Average
```

How do I transform "1/2/2016 - 1/2/2016, Every day, Daily Average" into "2016-01-02" for every date and order them by date?

Note: The string has two dates and they are the same, for every row, that's why I want to transform them into one date only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split by first space, select first value and convert to datetime with `format` parameter by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), last if necessary use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df['Date Range'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Range'].str.split().str[0], format='%d/%m/%Y')

df = df.sort_values('Date Range')
```